# integrate by part or taylor series

Tags: integration

I have a problem with calculating this integral: $$\theta(t) = \int_{t}^{\infty} \phi(z)dz= \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \exp(- \frac{1}{2}z^2) dz.$$

I tried with my friends using integration by parts and Taylor series, but I don't know how to do it to the end.

Please, help me :D

Comment: Yes! Because this integration is complementary cumulative distribution function of $N(0,1)$ :D

Comment: It cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. It is what it is.

Comment: This can be easily solved if $t=0$, I don't know otherwise, for $t=0$ answer will be $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Comment: So, maybe you have any idea how I should improve this inequality: $$\frac{\phi(t)}{t} - \frac{\phi(t)}{t^3} \leq \theta(t) \leq \frac{\phi(t)}{t}$$ without calculate this integer

Comment: I'm not sure, if I am coorect or if this helps, but you can write this integral as $$int_{0}^{ \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} exp(- \frac{z^2}{2} )dz - \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{2 \pi} exp(-\frac{z^2}{2})dz $$
 The integral of the first part can be reduced to gamma function (and multiplication by appropriate constants) and the result of the second can be written as erf(t) (and multiplication by appropriate constants). 
You can find out about these two functions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function. Hope this helps